# Db2 client setup

Tags: linux, terminal, db2

I am quite new to db2 and I have difficulties during setup remote client connection.
I installed a IBM runtime client and I want to connect to a remote db2 instance(administraded by our client, not us).
As far as I know I need to catalogue proper node and database. But for that purpose I need to use db2 command.
If I want to use it I got this kind of problem:
SQL10007N Message "-1390" could not be retrieved.  Reason code: "3".
I found that I should setup proper DB2INSTANCE environment variable, but when I do that, nothing changes and I still got same error message. On machine which I am trying to setup db2 client, I have nor db2 instance nor db2 server software, only the client. What am I missing?
I am using ssh connection and I used db2_install script for isntalling the db2 runtime client.

Comment: please edit your question to add detail (do not use comments) , With which tool or tools/languages do you need to connect to the database?  You only need to catalog when you want to use legacy cli methods of connecting, as used by languages like python, perl or any language or tool written in C/C++.

Comment: Look in the sqllib directory created by the client installer tool, to find a file called `db2profile`.  In your shell (bash) session, dot in that file like this `. /path/to/sqllib/db2profile`  (replace `/path/to` by whatever is your installation directory).  You can put that dot command in your shell startup file (example, `.bashrc`). After you have dotted in that file, the `db2` command line should then work.

Comment: The `db2_install` script installs the db2 code only. It *doesn't create* a db2 client instance which *must be created* to successfully work with remote databases. So, create a db2 instance owner, say, `db2inst1` user in OS and create the corresponding db2 client instance with the `.../db2icrt db2inst1` as root, if you installed the db2 code as root. Catalog a remote db2 instance and a database as `db2inst1`.